# Castle Windsor 3.0 Beta 1 Running in Mono

Tags: mono, castle-windsor

I am attempting to use Windsor 3 Beta 1 in Mono 2.6 and I am encountering a few issues. (Note that my tests all pass while running Windsor 3 Beta 1 on .Net 3.5)

Initially I tried the .Net 3.5 binaries available, upon doing so an exception was thrown while constructing a WindsorContainer (i.e. new WindsorContainer())

> System.ArrayTypeMismatchException : Source array type cannot be assigned to destination array type. 
>   at (wrapper stelemref) object:stelemref (object,intptr,object) 
>   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Type,Castle.Windsor.Diagnost ics.IDiagnostic`1[System.Object]].Add (System.Type key, IDiagnostic`1 value) [0x00000] in : 0 
>   at Castle.Windsor.Diagnostics.DefaultDiagnosticsSubSystem.AddDiagnostic[IAllCo mponentsDiagnostic](IAllComponentsDiagnostic diagnostic) [0x00000] in : 0 
>   at Castle.Windsor.Diagnostics.Extensions.AllComponents.Init (IKernel kernel, IDiagnosticsHost diagnosticsHost) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Castle.Windsor.Diagnostics.DefaultDiagnosticsSubSystem.Add (IContainerDebuggerExtension item) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Castle.Windsor.Diagnostics.DefaultDiagnosticsSubSystem.InitStandardExtensio ns () [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Castle.Windsor.Diagnostics.DefaultDiagnosticsSubSystem.Init (IKernelInternal kernel) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.AddSubSystem (System.String key, ISubSystem subsystem) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.RegisterSubSystems () [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel..ctor (IDependencyResolver resolver, IProxyFactory proxyFactory) [0x00000] in : 0 
>   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel..ctor (IProxyFactory proxyFactory) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel..ctor () [0x00000] in :0 
>   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel:.ctor () 
>   at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer..ctor () [0x00000] in :0 
>   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer:.ctor ()

After making some modifications to various files to compile Castle.Core and Castle.Windsor targeting Mono 2.6 (add MONO to several compiler directives (which may not be the right solution), I ran the tests and many failed.

I then used the Mono 2.6 binaries (yes the binaries that had many failing tests), and I received the same exception mentioned above.

Any ideas on what needs to be done to get Windsor 3 running in Mono?

Comment: First off - try a recent Mono version, currently 2.10.4 ( http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html ).

Comment: Getting closer...There are several tests that still fail with the following exception: `Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.ComponentActivatorException : ComponentActivator: could not proxy InterceptorFixture+TestJobStep
  ----> System.TypeInitializationException : An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Castle.Proxies.ITestJobStepProxy
  ----> System.ArgumentException : Cannot resolve method because it's declared in a generic class.
`

Comment: I was able to get the Windsor 3 Beta 1 .Net binaries to work under Mono 2.10.4.  All of my tests now pass.  I posted a similar question on the official [group](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users/browse_thread/thread/cf948753b89f0d97).  In it Krzysztof mentions that he is looking for help with making sure Castle works under Mono.